# symfony generate URL without route?

Tags: url, symfony1, urlencode

I want to generate a URL.

For example:

```
üäö ssd
```

When I do this with urlencode, it gives me:

```
%E3%BC%E3%A4%E3%B6+ssd
```

But when i submit a form, symfony generates a url like this:

```
üäö+ssd
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Doctrine_Inflector::urlize() to generate urls without special characters in them. It will remove all non-ASCII character and spaces if I remember correctly.